# MSVC bug? - Returned inner lambda with non-init-capture of outer lambda's by-ref parameter causes C2131 when outer lambda is passed a plain function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, c++17, language-lawyer

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Tf3o9f16K)'s the live minimal example demonstrating the issue, copied below along with error:

```cpp
constexpr auto foo = [](auto const& p) { return [p]{ return 1; }; };

void bar(){}
constexpr auto baz = foo(bar); // C2131
```

```
<source>(6): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(2): note: failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol
<source>(2): note: see usage of '<lambda_833637519c89a13e2555ac846bc40c61>::()::<lambda_13c809781a1aa438f693875c73cfce81>::p'
<source>(6): note: the call stack of the evaluation (the oldest call first) is
<source>(6): note: while evaluating function '<lambda_833637519c89a13e2555ac846bc40c61>::()::<lambda_13c809781a1aa438f693875c73cfce81> <lambda_833637519c89a13e2555ac846bc40c61>::operator ()<void(void)>(void (__cdecl &)(void)) const'
<source>(2): note: while evaluating function '<lambda_833637519c89a13e2555ac846bc40c61>::()::<lambda_13c809781a1aa438f693875c73cfce81>::<lambda_13c809781a1aa438f693875c73cfce81>(void (__cdecl &)(void))'
Compiler returned: 2
```

Some possible workarounds:

- make `bar` a function object, i.e. `constexpr auto bar = []{};`
- change `foo`'s param type to be by-value, i.e. `constexpr auto foo = [](auto p) { return [p]{ return 1; }; };`
- use init-capture for the inner lambda, i.e. `constexpr auto foo = [](auto const& p) { return [p = p]{ return 1; }; };`
- make `baz` non-`constexpr`, i.e. `const auto baz = foo(bar);`

Is it indeed a bug in MSVC¹ or a non-conformance in the compilers that accept the code above?

---

(¹) I've used *x64 msvc v19.35*, but [*x64 msvc v19.14* seems to be ok with the code](https://godbolt.org/z/oGT6znoTa).

Comment: similar to arrays, functions can decay to pointer but don't do it always, especially when deduction is involved (cf `std::size` to get size of a c-array). It works when you make it explicit https://godbolt.org/z/GPnco6sx7. Perpahs add the `language-lawyer` tag

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I've put that tag, given up on the lambda tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[expr.prim.lambda.capture]p10](https://wg21.link/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10.sentence-4):

> The type of such a data member is the referenced type if the entity is a reference to an object, **an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function**, or the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise.

(emphasis mine)

So with the closure types explicitly written out, it might look something like this:

```cpp
struct __foo_lambda_type {
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto operator()(T const& p) const {
        struct __inner_lambda_type {
            // (p is a reference to a function, capture by value creates a reference)
            T& p;

            constexpr auto operator()() const {
                return 1;
            }
        };
        return __inner_lambda_type{ p };
    };
};

constexpr auto foo = __foo_lambda_type{};

void bar(){}
constexpr auto baz = foo.operator()<void()>(bar);
```

... Which also doesn't compile in MSVC

It seems like the MSVC bug is that it can't use structs with function references in constant expressions

https://godbolt.org/z/5E6KP6boP

```cpp
void bar();

struct function_reference {
    void(&ref)();
    constexpr function_reference(void(&ctor_ref)()) :
        ref(ctor_ref)  // line (6)
        {}
};

constexpr auto f(void(&local_ref)()) {
    auto x = function_reference{local_ref};  // line (11)
    return x;
};

constexpr auto x = f(bar);  // line (15)
```

```
(15): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
( 6): note: failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol
( 6): note: see usage of 'function_reference::ref'
(15): note: the call stack of the evaluation (the oldest call first) is
(15): note: while evaluating function 'function_reference f(void (__cdecl &)(void))'
(11): note: while evaluating function 'function_reference::function_reference(void (__cdecl &)(void))'
```

---

The workaround is to capture a function pointer. `[p = p]` does this because it is equivalent to `auto lambda_member_p = p`, where `lambda_member_p` is deduced to have a function pointer type if `p` is a function reference.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Returned-inner-lambda-with-non-init-capt/10417723?ftype=problem&q=lambda+inner+returned+c2131&sort=newest).